# How do I copy an address onto an entity?

Tags: entities

This use case involves copying an address from CiviCRM into a field on a commerce product.

1. Create a product

Based on an event trigger

```
protected function createProduct(EntityInterface $group) {
  $user = User::load($this->currentUser->id());
  $user_hash = $user->uuid();
  $sku = $this->getMachineName($group->get('label')
    ->getString()) . '_' .  $user_hash;

  $variation = ProductVariation::create([
    'type' => 'basic',
    'sku' => $sku,
    'price' => new Price('10.00', 'GBP'),
  ]);
  $variation->save();

  $product = Product::create([
    'type' => 'basic',
    'title' => t($group->get('label')->getString()),
    'variations' => [$variation],
  ]);
  $this->setAddress($product);
  $product->save();
}
```

However, setAddress() is the challenge

```
 protected function setProductAddress($civiCrmAddress, $contact, EntityInterface $product) {
   $addressList = $product->get('field_address');
```

Which provides an AddressFieldItemList. How do I create an AddressItem field?

Not like this:     `$address = AddressItem::createInstance($addressDefinition);`

as I can't find $addressDefinition (ComplexDataDefinitionInterface)

Just create an array $address = ['country_code' => 'US]; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just create such an array $address and set it:

```
$product->set('field_adress', $address);
```